# What is considered the best way to style components in React with Emotion in terms of readability and performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, emotion, css-in-js

I guess there are 3 main ways to style components in Emotion

```
<div
    className={
        css`
        height: 150px;
        display: flex;
        padding: ${theme.defaultUnit}px ${theme.defaultUnit * 4}px;
        border-top: 1px solid red;
        border-right: 1px solid yellow;
        background: #fff;
        align-items: center;
        `,
    }
/>

const styles =  css`
        height: 150px;
        display: flex;
        padding: ${theme.defaultUnit}px ${theme.defaultUnit * 4}px;
        border-top: 1px solid red;
        border-right: 1px solid yellow;
        background: #fff;
        align-items: center;
        `, 
<div className={styles} />

const StyledContainer = styled.div`
     height: 150px;
     display: flex;
     padding: ${theme.defaultUnit}px ${theme.defaultUnit * 4}px;
     border-top: 1px solid red;
     border-right: 1px solid yellow;
     background: #fff;
     align-items: center;
`
<StyledContainer />
```

Out of those 3 is there one considered best? I don't like option 1 personally as it bloats components with css and makes them harder to read. But I was wondering if there was performance implications with option 2? and therefore does that make option 3 the best? wondering if anyone has insight on this

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on projects where one or all the above are used. It really comes down to culture and need.

No one has a final answer and the community is still debating the subject.
[Emotion best practices is evolving](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/381)

Object styles are easier to use and in my opinion closer to the concept of good functional and object oriented programming used by react.

A good [article on the subject](https://benmcmahen.com/why-i-choose-emotion/) talks more in detail about some of the pros and cons, but again it's mostly preference.

The best for a team is code that looks clean and is human readable that doesn't clutter the component.